# Wait for tap to end on UICollectionViewCell before setting isSelected to true

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

Currently, I have a `collectionView` and its only function is to let the user choose a color. When the user chooses a color (clicks a cell), a selected indicator (`UIView`) animates inside the `cell`, letting the user know that that certain color is selected. The core functionality is there, but my question is based more off of UI. When I scroll, the cell thinks I am clicking it and it sets `isSelected` to true for a second until I remove my finger from the cell. This causes an animation to happen at unwanted times. So, I think the problem is in `shouldSelectItemAt` in the `CollectionViewDelegate` methods. With `UIGestureRecognizer` I can measure whether or not the `sender state` has `.began` or `.ended`. Would my question call for this or something similar?

Here are the selection `collectionView` delegate methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = colorPreviewCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TrayColorPreviewCell
        // stuff with cell happens here
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let cell = colorPreviewCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TrayColorPreviewCell
        guard cell.isSelected else { return true }
        return false
    }
```

In the `TrayColorPreviewCell` (custom `UICollectionViewCell`) class, I use the `isSelected` to run the animation. This animation is the one that is happening repeatedly when scrolling.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            changeSelectionStatus()
        }
    }

func changeSelectionStatus() {
        if isSelected {
            // animation to indicate selection

        } else {
            // animation to indicate changed selection
        }

    }
```